# Solr boosting Requirement

Tags: solr, boosting

I am stuck in a particular scenario the ask is to add the boost (additive) after full calculation of score has been done
Example :
q=*:*&bq=field:xyz^5&bf=2&boost=10&bq=field2:abc^10 score would be (5+2+10)*10
Requirement is :
q=*:*&bq=field:xyz^5&bf=2&boost=10&bq=field2:abc^10 score would be ((5+2)*10)+10

Thanks in Advance